# Writing to render texture in Unity using Compute Shaders is slow?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am just learning Compute Shaders and experimenting with Unity ( i am not familiar with shaders too much), and i am trying to do something like a simple raycast and write to a render texture from a Compute Shader. Everything works just perfect, i get the wanted result. The ray-triangle intersections happens really fast - just less than a half of a second. However at the moment i try to apply a new color to the render texture, performance breaks down. The time needed jumps to 5 seconds. I couldn't break out of a loop without worsening the performance even more. I couldn't even use a bool flag in the loop which i could use outside the loop to update the texture colors if it is set to true in the loop.

The performance gets really bad. How would i update the render texture colors?

Here is the shader code: Any help is appreciated.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma kernel MainCS

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Triangle
{
    float3 v0;
    float3 v1;
    float3 v2;
    float3 n;
};

// Precomputed and set from C# script
struct Pixel
{
    float3   position;
    float3   direction;
    int      index;
    float    pixelColor;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define blocksize 8

// variables
int imageSize;

// buffers
RWStructuredBuffer<Pixel>        pixels    : register(u0); // UAV
RWTexture2D<float4>              rendTex   : register(u1); // UAV
const StructuredBuffer<Triangle> tris      : register(t0); // SRV


// This kernel writes some color in the current pixel if there is ray intersection with some of the triangles from the tris buffer.  In general works well but slow. The intersection part without writing to the render texture is SUPER FAST. When i attempt to write to the texture - gets SUPER SLOW. Render Texture random write is enabled from the C# script

[numthreads(blocksize,blocksize,1)]
void MainCS (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID, uint3 Gid : SV_GroupID, uint3 GTid : SV_GroupThreadID, uint GI : SV_GroupIndex )
{
    // Get the current pixel ID - pixels is 1D array
    int pixelID = (int)(id.y * imageSize + id.x);

    // Ray
    float3 rayO = pixels[pixelID].position;
    float3 rayD = pixels[pixelID].direction;

    // Intersection variables
    float3 pt0, pt1, pt2, edge0, edge1, edge2, cross1, cross2, cross3, n;
    float angle1, angle2, angle3;
    float r, _a, b;
    float3 w0, I;

    bool bIntersect = false;

    [loop][allow_uav_condition]
    for (uint tr = 0; tr < tris.Length; tr++)
    {
        // Somecalculations
        pt0 = tris[tr].v0; pt1 = tris[tr].v1; pt2 = tris[tr].v2;
        edge0 = rayO - pt0; edge1 = rayO - pt1; edge2 = rayO - pt2;

        // First check - is the ray intersecting the triangle
        if (dot(rayD, cross(edge0, edge1)) >= 0.0 ||
            dot(rayD, cross(edge1, edge2)) >= 0.0 ||
            dot(rayD, cross(edge2, edge0)) >= 0.0) continue;

        // Fiding the intersection point
        n = normalize(cross(pt0 - pt1, pt0 - pt2));
        w0 = rayO - pt0;
        _a = -dot(n, w0);
        b  =  dot(n, rayD);
        r  = _a / b;
        I = rayO + rayD * r;

        // Second check - before validate the hitpoint
        if (_a < 0.0)
        {
            // Here i would want to update texture colors

            // ==============================================
            // Variant 1 =======================================
            // Only update the texture without break;
            // Gives proper result but is SLOW - 3 seconds
            rendTex[id.xy] = float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            // if add break; - MUCH SLOWER
            break;

            // ===============================================
            // Variant 2 - Part 1 ==================================
            // rising flag to true - fast
            if(!bIntersect)
            {
                bIntersect = true;
            }
        }
    }

// Variant 2 - Part 2 - When using the flag - updating Render texture colror is SUPER SLOW but acurate
    if(bIntersect)
        rendTex[id.xy] = float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic branching is very expensive when programming on the GPU.

This is because of the way GPUs are designed.  A simplified view of how a CPU works: fetch an instruction, decode it, and then execute it on an ALU.  A GPU fetches an instruction, decodes it, and then executes it on a bunch of ALUs at the same time.  It steps through each line on each one of its threads at the same time, and it will need to run the program again for all of those pixels even if only one of those threads has to execute a different instruction.

Basically, avoid dynamic branching (if statements) where possible.  When you do a for loop with a conditional break, you're creating a lot of branches, which is the GPU's Achille's heel.  The flag is faster because the GPU is able to execute all those instructions on each thread no matter what.  Try to get as many of your threads to execute the same lines of code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to make something like a drawing tool that lets you draw on surfaces. I've built one of these before but this is done by drawing directly to the texture from Unity, not from the shader. Additionally, you don't need this to be a render texture unless you're trying to capture another camera's rendering and then compositing on top of that.

Shaders are usually very fast because they can parallelize the drawing of many pixels at once to the draw buffer. Whereas, writing to texture memory is much slower. Most likely your performance issues are due to the shader continuously updating the texture on every pixel of every frame. Lots of very small write operations. Imagine writing a novel by opening a text file, updating a single character, then closing it repeatedly.

What I'd suggest is drawing directly to the texture in Unity using [Texture2D.setPixels()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html). It allows you to batch the writes to texture memory by accepting an array of Unity Color objects and only sending those modified pixels when you call `texture.Apply()` on your texture.

Additionally, if you need to get the UV coordinates in texture space, there's  [RaycastHit.textureCoord](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html).

Here's the example provided in the Unity documentation for drawing to a texture based on where a raycast hits the surface of an object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera cam;
    void Start() {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
    void Update() {
        if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            return;

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
            return;

        Renderer rend = hit.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        MeshCollider meshCollider = hit.collider as MeshCollider;
        if (rend == null || rend.sharedMaterial == null || rend.sharedMaterial.mainTexture == null || meshCollider == null)
            return;

        Texture2D tex = rend.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
        Vector2 pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
        pixelUV.x *= tex.width;
        pixelUV.y *= tex.height;
        tex.SetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y, Color.black);
        tex.Apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. But i'm actually trying to make a GPU RayTracer - at least at it's basic level - shooting only primary rays and detecting triangles. All the data needed is precomputed in C# script and is uploaded to the Compute Shader using buffers and RWTexture2D. I did some research and thought using render texture is suited best for the purpose, while it allows random read write access - this option is enabled in the C# script before uploading the render texture to the GPU memory. Isn't that the proper way of writing information to a texture withing a ComputeShader ?